# Arial and Helvetica as safe web-fonts for every devices

Tags: css, fonts

Are Arial and Helvetica safe fonts for Windows Mac/Linux iOS and Android devices?

I made some tests and for example Arial and Helvetica are not displayed / loaded on Android.

There is a way to load this fonts on all the devices?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Arial and Helvetica won't be available on all devices. You should use a fallback font family like sans-serif

`font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`